# How to validate SmartSelect, Radio and Checboxes in [framework7]

Tags: validation, html-framework-7, dom7

We're having issues with validation on checkboxes, smart selects and radio fields in **framework 7 v3**

There is only validation examples for text inputs (url, email) [link to the docs](https://v3.framework7.io/docs/inputs.html#validation)

We tried the same approach from the text inputs in the checkbox and radio like the docs but it didn't work

Here's how we tried:

```
<input type="checkbox" placeholder="http..." required validate>
```

We are not getting the browser blocking from submitting when we place ***required*** and ***validate*** on the fields.